Blue/Green Deployment issue
I commit my code to GitHub, which triggers AWS CodePipeline. The code is then built and pushed to Amazon ECS for a blue-green deployment.
Currently, the deployment is stalling at Step 1, during the "Install" phase.
Regarding my setup:
In ECS:
Load Balancer Health:
    Listener protocol:port: HTTPS:443
    Target group name:protocol: services-ecs-green:HTTP

Target Groups:

    Target group 1: services-ecs-blue: HTTP/IP
    Target group 2: services-ecs-green: HTTP/IP

Configuration and Networking:

Service Configuration:

    Listener protocol:port: HTTP:80, HTTPS:443
    Task definition: revision: service-fastapi-master-branch
    Target group name:protocol: services-ecs-green:HTTP

Network Configuration:

    Target groups: services-ecs-green
    Load balancers: services-fastapi-alb

In Target Groups Configuration:
services-ecs-blue:
    Protocol: Port: HTTP: 8000
    Load Balancer: None
    Protocol version: HTTP1
    Health status details: Target group is not configured to receive traffic from the load balancer

services-ecs-green:
    Protocol: Port: HTTP: 8000
    Load balancer: ervices-fastapi-alb

In Load Balancers (Listeners and Rules):
Port HTTP:80 redirects to HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query} with a status code: HTTP_301

HTTPS:443 forwards to the target group services-ecs-green with 100% traffic.

I've noticed that my blue environment has no load balancer and is reporting a health status indicating that the target group is not configured to receive traffic from the load balancer.
Proposed Change:
If I modify the HTTPS:443 listener to have a default rule that forwards traffic to both blue and green environments as follows:
Forward to target group:
    services-ecs-blue: 90%
    services-ecs-green: 10%

When I try to deploy with this rule, I encounter the following error during deployment:
"TaskSet <ecs-svc/3591053252883737101> is behind prod listener arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:123456789:listener/app/services-fastapi-alb/6cf62bb31edb8bb6/79ecb5421871a5e5. Verify that the TaskSet <ecs-svc/3591053252883737101> is still serving production traffic and update the listener rule if required. For more information on updating listener rules, refer to AWS Documentation on Listener Rules."
